# JavaScript function response and chained promises

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code, before-save

I have a `Parse` `CloudCode` `beforeSave` function, which roughly does the following:

- Runs a query to check if there's a duplicate user to the one being saved;
- If there is NO duplicate, I call a `response.success()`, which means the code can go ahead and allow saving the new user;
- If, however, there is a duplicate, I want to take the `existing user`, fetch a `group` object and add the `existing user` to the `group`.

For this purpose, I am using chained promises to make the code cleaner. The code is below:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Contact", function(request, response) {

    var facebookID = request.object.get("facebookID");
    var email = request.object.get("email");

    var queryFb;
    if (facebookID) {
        queryFb = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        queryFb.equalTo("facebookID", facebookID);
    }

    var queryEmail;
    if (email) {
        queryEmail = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        queryEmail.equalTo("email", email);
    }

    var query;
    if (facebookID && email) {
        query = new Parse.Query.or(queryFb, queryEmail);
    } else if (facebookID) {
        query = queryFb;
    } else {
        query = queryEmail;
    }

    var user;

    query.first().then(function(user) {

        if (!user) {

            response.success();

        } else {

            var groupQuery = new Parse.Query("Group");
            groupQuery.equalTo("title", "ssAll");
            groupQuery.equalTo("owner", request.user);
            return groupQuery.first();
        }

    }).then(function(group) {

        group.addUnique("contacts", user);
        return group.save();

    }).then(function(success) {

        response.error("NOT ERROR - new object was NOT created");

    }, function(error) {

        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

In my test case, the query returns `!user`, so the `response.success()` message is called - all good. However, this response seems to then travel down the promise chain, which is intended for the case when the query returns a `user` object. And so, my function terminates with an error on line `group.addUnique("contacts", user);` because, obviously, the `group` object is `undefined`.

How do I work around this issue?

Comment: Its easy to fix, but the code has all kinds of users mentioned:  `var user`, this conflicts with the function parameter `user` in the the then block, then both are ignored by referring to `request.user`.  I can give you abstract advice about how to make the promises work, but its hard to do much specific b/c I don't understand the user references

Comment: `request.user` is an object passed with `request` parameter of the function. `user` is another user that is the result of the query, and `var user` is an external reference of the latter (provided I can do it like this) - I need this external reference because I am using the `user` object in another function down the `promise` chain - see line `group.addUnique("contacts", user);`. Let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: I think I get it.  Can you edit the missing code in `// set up the query` into the question?

Comment: The code has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code needed a few improvements.  The key improvement was to provide  consistent starting conditions to the second promise's resolution (the second `then` block).  The OP code called response.success() in the case where there was no existing user.  This is fine, except the execution still falls through to the next resolution, in one case with an undefined `group` parameter.

The new code fixes that by returning either the `existingUser` (after the group has been updated) or `null`.  Null tells the next promise resolution to call `success()` and allow the save to proceed, otherwise, block the save.

Also note, it *is* a mistake for the first block's `user` parameter to conflict with the `var user` in the enclosing scope.  I tried to use variable naming below to highlight the two different types of users the code considers...

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Contact", function(request, response) {
    var facebookID = request.object.get("facebookID");
    var email = request.object.get("email");
    // moved into a function so we can test and deal with it tersely
    findUserByEmailOrFB(email, facebookID).then(function(existingUser) {
        return (existingUser)? addContactToGroupOwnedBy(request.user, existingUser) : null;
    }).then(function(existingUser) {
        if (existingUser) {
            response.error("NOT ERROR - new object was NOT created");
        } else {
            response.success();
        }
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});

// find the group owned by ownerUser, add contactUser to its contacts return a promise fulfilled as contactUser
function addContactToGroupOwnedBy(ownerUser, contactUser) {
    var groupQuery = new Parse.Query("Group");
    groupQuery.equalTo("title", "ssAll");
    groupQuery.equalTo("owner", ownerUser);
    return groupQuery.first().then(function(group) {
        group.addUnique("contacts", contactUser);
        return group.save().then(function() { return contactUser; });
    });
}

function findUserByEmailOrFB(email, facebookID) {
    var queryFb;
    if (facebookID) {
        queryFb = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        queryFb.equalTo("facebookID", facebookID);
    }
    var queryEmail;
    if (email) {
        queryEmail = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        queryEmail.equalTo("email", email);
    }
    var query;
    if (facebookID && email) {
        query = new Parse.Query.or(queryFb, queryEmail);
    } else if (facebookID) {
        query = queryFb;
    } else {
        query = queryEmail;
    }
    return query.first();
}
```

Comment: In case `findUserByEmailOrFB()` function returns no `existingUser`, the next function will `return null`. Does that still invoke the next promise?

Comment: Yes, it will be invoked with null as the param

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked for me. I tried simplifying my code with promises, but there's another step in simplifying, which is wrapping text in stand-alone functions and making code more readable and self-documenting as well.

Comment: At least one possible failure case is not catered for. In `findUserByEmailOrFB()`, `queryEmail;` could be undefined at the point where `query = queryEmail` is called, in which case an error will be thrown (and not caught). Depending on what should happen under when `query` cannot be formed, either a resolved or rejected promise should be returned.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - that was just OP code, apparently working, that I copied and factored out.  You're right about the case that will generate a failure.  Having at least one of those properties set ought to be beforeSave criterion for the object.  The OP is likely enforcing this on the caller side, but it would be better to add the check instead of (or additionally) in the cloud function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are always resolving the first promise regardless of whether checking for the user was successful (no such user yet) or not. However, actually you don't ever have to resolve the promise. I suggest you separate the error case like this:

```
query.first().then(function(user) {
    if (!user) {
        response.success();
    } else {
        addUserToGroup(request.user).then(function() {
            response.error("NOT ERROR - new object was NOT created");
        }, function(error) {
            response.error(error);
        });
    }
});

function addUserToGroup(user) {
    var groupQuery = new Parse.Query("Group");
    groupQuery.equalTo("title", "ssAll");
    groupQuery.equalTo("owner", user);
    return groupQuery.first().then(function(group) {
        group.addUnique("contacts", user);
       return group.save();
    });
}
```

As you can see, the first promise doesn't ever have to be resolved because the result is not used anyway.

Comment: Hi. Your solution definitely works, thanks! I accepted the other answer as it was first and it is correct as well. I up-voted yours though.